# Narrowing line of differential pair for DVI connector

Tags: differential, impedance-matching, hdmi

Is this a big problem with reflections (caused by missing impedance) if I'll trace differential pairs like it showed on picture?[image: narrowing line for DVI connection]
I'm designing DVI driving on freq not more than 640 MHz.

How you can see, I narrowed TMDS_D1+ and TMDS_D0+ signal lines from 0,3mm to 0,150 mm, to pass they into the connector. I need it, because my PCB vendor cannot make gaps less then 0,125 mm. But for compliance with impedance I must do line with/gap 0,3/0,2 mm (distance to reference plane 0,4 mm)

Comment: That’s usually where you end up. You can measure the eye diagram and determine if you are still within specifications or not. Might be simulation tools too for this.

Comment: I ask, because, perhaps, someone has experience in such things.

Comment: Yes, and that’s the solution experienced people end up with, narrowing tracks.

Comment: If your pcb-cad software allows changing pad shapes try changing the lower 3 pads to vertical ovals (or rounded rectangles), that may give enough clearance to keep the original trace width.

Comment: I'm afraid, that my pcb vendor, can't do holes like that.

Answer (score 1):

A solution was founded, by decreasing distance to reference plane from 0,4 mm to 0,2mm , that helps decrease width/gap from 0.3mm/0.2mm to 0.15mm/0.15mm, 
which corresponds differential impedance 100 Ohm. So with lenght matching it looks like it shown on the picture.[image]